# What was Feynman's famous formula?

Tags: soft-question, nuclear-physics, terminology, history

In [Welton(1983), Memories of Feynman](http://www.scribd.com/doc/48928105/Ted-Welton-Memories-of-Richard-Feynman#scribd), Welton mentions two formulas which he denotes as Feynman's Famous Formula (FFF) and FFF #2.

Which famous formulas is he talking about? Is he maybe talking about the [Bethe-Feynman efficiency formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe%E2%80%93Feynman_formula)? Are these formulas still classified or does somebody know how these formulas look like?

Comment: Asmaier, I think it's reasonably probable that you have indeed found "FFF" already from the context of the article. As to the other one, I don't know.

Comment: [...when he first met the young Richard Feynman at a conference, he said after a long silence, "I have an equation. Do you have one too?".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Dirac)

Answer (score 5):

There is something famously called "Feynman's famous formula", which comes up in QFT calculations, which I imagine must be the second FFF referred to in Welton's account. It reads:

$$\frac1{a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n} = \int_{x \in \Delta^{n-1}} \frac1{(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i)^n} d\sigma$$

where $\Delta^{n-1}$ denotes the simplex $\{x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n: x_i \geq 0, x_1 + \ldots + x_n = 1\}$ of dimension $n-1$, and $d\sigma$ denotes Lebesgue measure on this simplex, normalized so that its total volume is $1$. For example, in the case $n=2$, it may be written as

$$\frac1{ab} = \int_0^1 dx \frac1{(ax + b(1-x))^2}.$$

In any case, many people do refer to this as "Feynman's famous formula", for example Witten in the book Quantum Fields and Strings (Proposition 1.3, page 427), or in the article [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=WXPSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&dq=%22feynman%27s+famous+formula%22&source=bl&ots=li5bR6SbER&sig=Usm9FFxYiR5i_BJOqdNdtFy_vS0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw66jB_KDNAhXHej4KHdiFCRkQ6AEIMTAE#v=onepage&q=%22feynman%27s%20famous%20formula%22&f=false) (from Particle Physics: Càrgese 1989). Apparently Feynman first wrote about this in a letter to Bethe:

> "I am the possessor of a swanky new scheme to do each problem with one less energy denominator. It is based on the great identity [the previously displayed formula] so 2 energy denominators may be combined to one -- reserving the parametric $x$ integration to the indefinite future (there's the rub of course)."

(Source: QED And The Men Who Made It: Dyson, Feynman, Schwinger, and Tomonaga, by Silvan Schweber, page 453.)